# iOS makes the iphone5 hot after play for a while

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-management

I wrote a game and put it into iphone5 for testing.
It becomes very hot on hand.

I have put it in Instrument and it shows that there are 3% CPU only.

However, the memory is kept growing to around 250mb.
Is it related to memory leakage which lead to high temperature?

Comment: Can be. Show some code.

Comment: The game has over over 100k lines of code as a complicated RPG. I am difficult to show all codes here. But I have used the following classes: few CAEmitterLayer and many UIImageView for graphics and 3 to 5 UIView animation at the same time when players move.

Comment: Well, as long as you wont show us some code we can't really tell whether it's some kind of 'memory leakage'. High tempereature can have multiple reasons from too many background processes ove memory allocation issues up to a broken device.

Comment: May I know other than Xcode instrument, any other 3rd party tools that can help to profile the memory and CPU for the application over iphone? thanks